# JAXB namespace issue with extended annotated class' member

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, xml-namespaces, jaxb2

I have 3 annotated classes (I deliberatly removed getters, setters, and so on to make code more readable):

Result.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "resultat")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "state", "content" })
public class Result {
    protected State state;
    protected Content content;
}
```

Content.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "content")
@XmlSeeAlso({ Job.class })
public class Content {
}
```

and Job.java which extends Content:

```
@XmlType(name = "job", propOrder = { "status" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "job")
public class JobStatus extends Content {
    protected String status;
}
```

I am setting a Job instance as the value of the content member of the result class, but i get the following generated xml file:

```
<result>
    <state>
        <tag>value</tag>
    </state>
    <content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="job">
        <status>ok</status>
    </content>
</result>
```

But it is not a valid xml file and i can not validate it against the following schema because of the "xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="job"" part since job is not a type from http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="result">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="state">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="tag"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="content">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="status"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How can i change my JAXB configuration to avoid this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the JAXB configuration, but in the design of the Schema vs the Java Classes.

The Java Class `Content` does not comply with your Schema, since the element `status` is defined in the Schema but not in the Java Class.
Also, you do not define `job` in your Schema.

The attribute `xsi:type` is used for inheritance. Since your JobStatus Class inherits from Content, in XML its displayed as `content` of type `job`.

I think the best solution is to remove the element `status` from `content` in your Schema and then define `job` in your Schema, like so:

```
<complexType name="job">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="content">
            <sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="status"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Comment: +1 - FYI - Here is how the JAXB mappings could be changed to support this use case:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993543/jaxb-namespace-issue-with-extended-annotated-class-member/17995209#17995209

Answer (score 3):

[W A is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994543/383861) that your JAXB implementation is doing exactly what you told it to do (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html).  If you don't want to change your XML schema, below is how you can change your mappings.

### Java Model

**Result**

We will use the `@XmlElement` annotation on the `content` field to indicate that the real type is `Job` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html).

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = { "state", "content" })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Result {
    protected State state;

    @XmlElement(type=Job.class)
    protected Content content;
}
```

**Content**

We will use the `@XmlTransient` annotation on the `Content` class to remove it from the inheritance hierarchy (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html).

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlTransient
public class Content {
}
```

**Job**

`Job` is mapped normally.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Job extends Content {
    protected String status;
}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Result.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17993543/input.xml");
        Result result = (Result) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(result,System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <state>
        <tag>value</tag>
    </state>
    <content>
        <status>ok</status>
    </content>
</result>
```

Comment: Actually many classes extends Content, Job is just one of them. Thus Result is a Standard Response and different contents may be embedded into it. I can't manage to get your solution working with different classes extending content, is this possible?